# How to use avconv filters after encoding?

Tags: ffmpeg, avconv

I have avconv command

```
avconv  -i file -s [new size options] -vf "[filters]" /root/converted/1.mp4
```

Avconv use filters before encoding, but I need after. I need one avconv command:

```
Resize video first
Use filters second
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing input format (you did not provide it), this is a best guess what to do:
`avconv -i file -y -s [new size options] - | avconv -i - -vf "[filters]" /root/converted/1.mp4`